# How to use timer in parallel using multiprocessing module in PYCHARM/python

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to run a timer in parallel with the main thread.

About the program:

I want to send an image from the server to the client. The image is sent to the client as packets through **UDP socket**. 
The purpose of the timer is to control the transmission. 
If the time taken to send a packet is greater than 10 ms, the timer stops and hence the packet will be resent. For instance, let's say during the 100th packet transmission, a delay of 1 second is made deliberately to check the program, at the point, the timer should reset(because 10 ms is the threshold) and the packet should be resent.

I used

```
multirocesssing.Process(target=countdown), 
process = []
```

`p1.start` will start the process
`process.append(p1)` to add the `p1` process to the list

To communicate among the process, I used flag as a global variable and also as a process value.

```
flag = multiprocessing.Value()
```

can you please help

I used MULTIPROCESSING module to accomplish the goal.

ATTACHING THE CODE.

```
  def countdown(flag):
    process_ID = os.getpid()        #This module in Python will get the process ID when called.
    print(f"Process ID: {process_ID}")
    system_time = time.time()
    timeout = system_time + 1
    while True:
        if flag.Value == 1:
            break
        if (time.time() > timeout) and (flag.Value == 0):
            flag.Value = 1
            break

    def make_packet(outgoing_file, file_size):  # The make packet function takes two arguments; 
                                                    those two arguments are also specified by the client.
        global clientAddress, p1
        flag = multiprocessing.Value('i', 1)

        packet = outgoing_file.read(1024)  # Making the first packet by 1024 bytes.
        num_of_try = 0  # Number of tries to send the total number of packets 100%
        packet_num = 0
        fake_checksum = hashlib.md5(packet).hexdigest()  # Fake checksum to make errors intentionally.
        processes = []
        while packet_num != file_size:
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=countdown, args=(flag,))

        print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        if packet_num % 2 == 0:
            seq_num = '0'  # Current Sequence number.
        else:
            seq_num = '1'  # Next Sequence number.

        check_sum = hashlib.md5(packet).hexdigest()  # Calculating the checksum value using hashlib
        rdt_send(seq_num, packet, check_sum)  # Preparing seq_num, packet and checksum for transmission.
        flag.Value = 0                                                   #Start the timer
        processes.append(p1)
        p1.start()
        #
        if num_of_try == 554:
            print("MESS UP")            #Creating a delay of 1second to deliberately make TIMEOUT.
            time.sleep(1)

        received_ack, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)  # Receiving the request from the client throuh serverSocket and moving it to the holder "message".
        received_ack = received_ack.decode()  # Decoding the response from the client.
        print("Received ack - " + received_ack)  # Printing the received ack
        checksum_of_received_ack = hashlib.md5(received_ack.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()  # Calculating the checksum of the received ACK.
        print("CALCULATED Checksum of the received ACK - " + str(checksum_of_received_ack))
        received_checksum_from_client, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)  # Receiving checksum of the ACK from the client
        received_checksum_from_client = received_checksum_from_client.decode()  # Decoding the checksum received from the client.
        received_checksum_from_client = str(received_checksum_from_client)  # Converting the received checksum from
        print("Received checksum of the ACK - " + received_checksum_from_client)
        # print("Flag is " + str(flag))

        if flag.Value == 1:                   #If timeout happens, then flag is set to 1
            print("flag became 1 - Timeout happened")
            dupe_ack = received_ack     # Receiving the request from the client through serverSocket and moving it to the holder "message".
            dupe_checksum = received_checksum_from_client
            continue

        if checksum_of_received_ack == received_checksum_from_client:  # Comparing 'calculated checksum of the ACK' and the 'received checksum of the ACK from the client'.
            print("Entered first condition")
            if received_ack == seq_num:  # If the checksums match, then comparing 'received ack' and 'sequence number generated'
                print("Entered second condition")
                flag.Value = 1              #STOPPING THE TIMER
                # p1.join()
                next_packet = outgoing_file.read(1024)  # The next packet (1024 bytes) is read.
                packet = next_packet  # After receiving the positive Acknowledge, the next packet becomes the current packet.
                packet_num = packet_num + 1
                # print("GOOD ACK, FLAG IS " + str(flag))
                #flag.Value = 0             #RESTARTING THE TIMER
            # else:
                # flag.Value = 1        #BAD ACK, THEN STOP THE TIMER.
                # p1.join()
                # flag = 0      #THEN RESTART THE TIMER.
        # else:
            # flag.Value = 1            #BAD ACK, THEN STOP THE TIMER.
            # t1.join()
        num_of_try = num_of_try + 1  # Incrementing the number of try
        print("Packet number is : " + str(packet_num))
        print("number of try - " + str(num_of_try))

    # while packet_num != 0:
    #     p1.join()

    outgoing_file.close()  # Outgoing_file is closed.

****ERRORS I RECEIVED****
```

This is the error I am receiving every time the program compiles.

```
 File "C:\Users\Siyal\Phase_3\Phase_4_Server.py", line 13, in <module>
    serverSocket.bind((serverName, serverPort))  # Binding the IP and Port.
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Phase_3\Phase_4_Server.py", line 13, in <module>
    serverSocket.bind((serverName, serverPort))  # Binding the IP and Port.
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Siyal\Python 3.7.3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
```